# Exporting Client Cert to Backend with Zuul

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, client-certificates, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

It is possible to export/forward the client certificate to the backend services using Zuul as a proxy/load balancer?  I finally have a working example of zuul with spring-cloud using https and forwarding requests to a secure service on the backend using https as well. Now I need to forward the client's certificate information in addition to using https.  You can do this with Apache and Tomcat using the [SSLOptions +StdEnvVars/+ExportCertData](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/proxy.html), which adds the information to the headers, but I don't see how to do this with Zuul.  Does anyone know how you can do this?

Comment: Zuul is basically a blank slate.  Right now, you would need to write a filter and set those headers yourself.

Comment: >>> working example of zuul with spring-cloud using https and forwarding requests to a secure service on the backend using https <<<   am facing few issues with this, could you please let me know if there is any additional configuration required to achieve this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478146/error-when-zuul-routing-to-a-https-url

Comment: @yathirigan I just posted some info to your question. Sorry for the delay, hopefully it helps you out!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478146/error-when-zuul-routing-to-a-https-url/32620797#32620797