# Zuul proxy and ssl

Tags: spring-boot, https, netflix-zuul

I have a Spring boot project that is setup as a zuul proxy that is functioning as a api gateway for my rest services. I am now having problems with https which makes sense because I haven't configured https yet. One solution is to run nginx on port 443 and then forward all requests to the zuul proxy however that is extra overhead. So that is no solution.

Do I have to configure the zuul proxy to use the certificates or do I have to configure all the individual rest services?
What does the zuul proxy do with incoming requests? Does it forward the request or create a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicated, if this answer helps you please someone marks as duplicated this questions else let me know what is the difference? . [Error when Zuul routing to a HTTPS url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478146/error-when-zuul-routing-to-a-https-url)

Comment: Creating a new certificate of the type pkcs12 worked. Thanks.